# How to get reports of a puppet node using puppetdb api?

Tags: puppet

How do I get reports from a puppet node using [puppetdb report api](https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/4.2/api/query/v4/reports.html)?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the [query parameters](https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/4.2/api/query/v4/ast.html), it seems like following will do the work:

```
curl -X GET puppet.foo.com:8180/pdb/query/v4/reports -d 'limit=1' -d 'query=["=", "certname", "node.foo.com"]'
```